# css of jquery ui autocomplete not being applied

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying to implement jQuery ui's autocomplete.  It's working, except that the css isn't being applied.
1) The list of colleges that appears is styled like a normal ul.
2) "11 results are available, use up and down arrow keys to navigate" shows up and I don't want it to.

See my [my website](http://www.collegeanswerz.com/) to see it live.

I want it to be like the default functionality [here](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).

I followed the advice [here](https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails) to install jQuery ui, and [here](https://github.com/fatdude/jquery-ui-themes-rails) to install themes.

Here is my code.  What can I do to get the styling to be like the default functionality example?

`application.html.erb`

```
 <%= form_tag("/search", :method => 'get', :id => 'search_text', :class => 'form_search ui-autocomplete') do -%> 
    <div id="search"> <%= search_field_tag :search, params[:search], :placeholder => 'enter college', :id => "search_field", :class => 'input-medium search-query ui-autocomplete' %> </div>
<% end -%>
```

`home.js`

```
    $("#search_field").autocomplete({
      source: [
      "Adelphi University",
      "American University",
      "Andrews University",
      "Arizona State University",
      "Ashland University",
      "Auburn",
      "Wheaton - Illinois",
      "Wheaton - Massachusetts",
      "Whitman",
      "Wofford" ]
    });

$("#search_text").submit(function() {
        if ($("#search_field").val() == "Adelphi University")
        {
            window.location.href = "/adelphi-university";
            return false;
        }
        else if ($("#search_field").val() == "American University")
        {
            window.location.href = "/american-university";
            return false;
        }
        else if ($("#search_field").val() == "Andrews University")
        {
            window.location.href = "/andrews-university";
            return false;
        }
   });
```

UPDATE (not sure if relevant, but...)

`college.rb`

```
class College < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :url, :public, :years, :category, :calendar, :location, :setting, :retention, :created_at, :updated_at, :graduation4, :graduation6, :degrees, :rotc, :sat_submit, :act_submit, :sat_math_25, :sat_math_75, :sat_reading_25, :sat_reading_75, :sat_writing_25, :sat_writing_75, :sat_composite_25, :sat_composite_75, :act_math_25, :act_math_75, :act_english_25, :act_english_75, :act_writing_25, :act_writing_75, :act_composite_25, :act_composite_75, :acceptance_rate, :enrolled, :gpa375, :gpa35, :gpa325, :gpa3, :gpa25, :high_school_tenth, :high_school_quarter, :high_school_half, :sat_math_700, :sat_math_600, :sat_math_500, :sat_math_400, :sat_math_300, :sat_reading_700, :sat_reading_600, :sat_reading_500, :sat_reading_400, :sat_reading_300, :sat_writing_700, :sat_writing_600, :sat_writing_500, :sat_writing_400, :sat_writing_300, :act_composite_30, :act_composite_24, :act_composite_18, :act_composite_12, :act_math_30, :act_math_24, :act_math_18, :act_math_12, :act_english_30, :act_english_24, :act_english_18, :act_english_12, :very_important, :important, :considered, :student_faculty, :class_20, :class_49, :class_50, :majors, :law, :business, :medical, :other_grad, :us_news_ranking, :top_25_grad, :enrollment, :graduate_enrollment, :in_state, :out_of_state, :male, :female, :ethnicity, :frats, :sororities, :on_campus, :freshman_on_campus, :in_state_tuition, :out_of_state_tuition, :room_and_board, :with_need_got_aid, :got_need_fully_met, :percent_need_met, :scholarships, :loans, :cost_30, :cost_48, :cost_75, :cost_110, :cost_111, :requirements, :majors_offered_link, :ap_credit, :scholarships_link, :map, :street_view, :housing, :food, :weather, :dorms, :dorm_urls, :science_majors, :social_science_majors, :humanities_majors, :business_majors, :engineering_majors, :professional_majors, :area_studies_majors

  def self.search(search)
    if search
      find(:all, :conditions => ['UPPER(name) LIKE ?', "%#{search.upcase}%"])
    else
      find(:all)
    end
  end

end
```

`static_pages_controller.rb`

```
def search
  @colleges = College.search(params[:search])
end
```

UPDATE - Did I Install jQuery UI Themes Properly?

- I used [this](https://github.com/fatdude/jquery-ui-themes-rails).
- When I run `bundle install`, this all shows up: `Using jquery-rails (2.2.1) 
  Using jquery-tablesorter (1.5.0) 
  Using jquery-ui-rails (4.0.4) 
  Using jquery-ui-themes (0.0.11)`
- `application.css` has `*= require jquery.ui.all
  *= require jquery-ui/smoothness
  *= require_self
  *= require_tree .`
- I was confused by "Helper" and "Rake Tasks".  They don't seem applicable for me.

UPDATE - Development Environment

```
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="ui-id-1" tabindex="0" style="display: none; width: 861px; position: relative; top: -858.03125px; left: 715px;">
    <li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation"><a id="ui-id-2" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Adelphi University</a></li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation"><a id="ui-id-3" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">American University</a></li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation"><a id="ui-id-4" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Andrews University</a></li>
```

Comment: I'd see if the theme/jquery UI CSS is installed correctly. When looking at your live website, for example, the class `.ui-helper-hidden-accessible` isn't in your CSS per Chrome's inspector.

Comment: hmm, that sounds like it makes sense.  I'll look into it.

Comment: I think I installed it correctly.  See the update to my question.

Comment: I searched the CSS resources used in your live site and there are no `.ui-` classes to be found. Do the jQuery UI styles seem to work in your dev environment and/or show up in the CSS when you inspect?

Comment: The website looks the same in the development environment (ie. the autocomplete isn't styled).  However, when I inspect element, I see some `ui-` classes.  See the update to my question.

Comment: @Adam_Zerner The classes are in the DOM, but they aren't in the actual CSS resources, so there are no rules to apply. Maybe post your `Gemfile` as an additional reference (or in pastebin or something)? The CSS is missing the asset pipeline somehow.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36589/discussion-between-adam-zerner-and-chucknelson)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `application.css` manifest may not be loading. Ensure the following is in whatever layout you're using:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all" %>
```